Is it possible to render a preview of HEIC images with ReactJS?
I added a functionality to a website for uploading HEIC images, so the images are uploaded and sent to the backend for conversion to JPEG and storage.
The thing is, there's a preview of the images uploaded (and also a cropper) on the website, but that only works for JPEG and PNG images, not for HEIC.
So my question is: Can I render a preview of a HEIC image without converting it on the client side?
